# @content $key= vs @if in dust

Tags: dust.js

I have the following code:

```
{#data.merchantModel}
<div class="address">
{@content $key="content:combinedAddr" merchantAddress1="{merchantAddress1}" merchantAddress2="{merchantAddress2}"/}
</div>
{:else}
<div class="address">{merchantAddress1}</div>
more code...
{/data.merchantModle}
```

I'm working with Webcore/NodeApp but everything after the {:else} doesn't get rendered. If I comment it out everything is fine. Not sure why webcore doesn't like the {:else} but was wondering if there's another way to write the above code?
Still trying to wrap my head around dust.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to close your content tag and model is misspelled on the closing tag:

```
{#data.merchantModel}
<div class="address">
{@content $key="content:combinedAddr" merchantAddress1="{merchantAddress1}" merchantAddress2="{merchantAddress2}"/}
</div>
{:else}
<div class="address">{merchantAddress1}</div>
more code...
{/content}
{/data.merchantModel}
```